# Discord.js dynamically add options to slash command with .addChoices()

Tags: javascript, async-await, scope, discord.js

I have a slash command that requires 3 choices from the user: team1, team2, and how many games. I'm adding those as parameters for the command like this:

```
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('addgame')
        .setDescription('Sets up a game for placing bets.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('team1')
                .setDescription('Team 1')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'Bilibili Gaming', value: 'Bilibili Gaming'},
                    { name: 'JDG Gaming', value: 'JDG Gaming'},
                    { name: 'Gen.G', value: 'Gen.G'},
                    { name: 'T1', value: 'T1'},
                    { name: 'Cloud9', value: 'Cloud9'},
                    { name: 'Golden Guardians', value: 'Golden Guardians'},
                    { name: 'G2 Esports', value: 'G2 Esports'},
                ))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('team2')
                .setDescription('Team 2')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'Bilibili Gaming', value: 'Bilibili Gaming'},
                    { name: 'JDG Gaming', value: 'JDG Gaming'},
                    { name: 'Gen.G', value: 'Gen.G'},
                    { name: 'T1', value: 'T1'},
                    { name: 'Cloud9', value: 'Cloud9'},
                    { name: 'Golden Guardians', value: 'Golden Guardians'},
                    { name: 'G2 Esports', value: 'G2 Esports'},
                ))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('series')
                .setDescription('Number of games')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: '1', value: '1'},
                    { name: '3', value: '3'},
                    { name: '5', value: '5'},
                )),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // Set up team information
        const teamList = await getTeams();
        const team1 = interaction.options.getString('team1');
        const team2 = interaction.options.getString('team2');
    ...
```

Not only are the `.addChoices()` properties redundant here and harder to maintain, but I actually get those same values from the database later in the slash command using a `getTeams()` function. I'm wondering how I could call that `getTeams` async function and use the result to populate `addChoices()`?

I could do something like this:

```
const teamList = await getTeams();
const choices = teamList.map(team => ({ name: team.name, value: team.value }));
...

.addChoices(...choices)
```

However, because `getTeams()` is an async function I can't use `await` outside of the `async execute(interaction)` method.

Is what I'm wanting to do not possible? If I had to restructure the slash command to achieve this, what would that look like? Any advice appreciated.

EDIT:
I even tried doing something like this in my index.js:

```
async function fetchTeamList() {
    const teamList = await getTeams();
    const teams = teamList.map(team => ({ name: team.Name, value: team.Name }));
    return teams;
}
...

    fetchTeamList().then(teams => {
        console.log(teams);
        module.exports.teams = teams;
    });
```

And then importing `teams` in my slash command file but that didn't work either. I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do is possible...
Using Node.js v18.17.0 and  discord.js: ^14.11.0

EDIT:

I have tried this as well:

```
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('addgame')
        .setDescription('Sets up a game for placing bets.')
        .addStringOption(async option =>{
            const teamList = await getTeams();
            const choices = teamList.map(team => ({ name: team.name, value: team.value }));
            return option
                .setName('team1')
                .setDescription('Team 1')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(...choices)
        })
```

As was recommended in an answer but this throws an error dealing with the ```@sapphire/shapeshif`package. I believe this isn't working because I'm  using an asynchronous callback for`addStringOption```` to fetch the team choices dynamically but the subsequent options are added synchronously... which might cause a problem?